# .toLocaleDateString() Not Working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have the below code which prints out the date which is 10 working days from now.  In Opera and Chrome it works as I expected and prints:
Thursday, November 17, 2011

However in Firefox (6.0.2) it prints out: 11/17/2011

Does anyone know why the date isn't getting printed as a string in Firefox?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function businessDays(n){
        var D=new Date();
        var num=Math.abs(n);
        var tem,count=0;
        var dir= (n<0)? -1: 1;
        while(count< num){
            D= new Date(D.setDate(D.getDate()+dir));
            tem=D.getDay();
            if(tem!=0 && tem!=6) ++count;
        }
        return D;
    }
    var D=businessDays(10).toLocaleDateString(); //string
    document.write(D);
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah perhaps you should specify if this is running in the same machine. As it seems the issue is with the system not the browser.

Comment: Yes, I was on the same machine.  However, I have since tried FF on a different machine and it worked as I had hoped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Mozilla documentation, the format can vary wildly depending on the user's location and computer settings.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

> The exact format depends on the platform, locale and user's settings.