# Formatted date not coming proper in Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, safari

I am trying to run the below code in Safari browswer but the date is not coming properly in the alert box. It shows correct date in Google chrome. In safari it shows " Tuesday 23rd March, 2015 "  and in Chrome it shows " 23 Mar 2015".

Does anyone knows why it is happening?

```
function getFormattedDate(input){
var pattern=/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)$/;
var result = input.replace(pattern,function(match,p1,p2,p3){
    var months=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Dec'];
    return (p2<10?"0"+p2:p2)+" "+months[(p1-1)]+" "+p3;
});
alert(result);
}
d1= new Date();
d2= d1.toLocaleDateString();
alert(d2);
getFormattedDate(d2);
```

Comment: update your safari browser, and check'

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this thread.

[toLocaleDateString() is not returning dd/mm/yyyy format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719346/tolocaledatestring-is-not-returning-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

You can use this code adopted from the answer written by Niet the Dark Absol adapted for you.

```
function getFormattedDate(input){
var pattern=/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)$/;
var result = input.replace(pattern,function(match,p1,p2,p3){
    var months=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Dec'];
    return (p2<10?"0"+p2:p2)+" "+months[(p1-1)]+" "+p3;
});
alert(result);
}

var dateobj = new Date();
function pad(n) {return n < 10 ? "0"+n : n;}
var d2 = pad(dateobj.getMonth()+1)+"/"+pad(dateobj.getDate())+"/"+dateobj.getFullYear();
alert(d2);
getFormattedDate(d2);
```