# Chrome toLocaleDateString returning wrong format

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date-formatting

Running `(new Date()).toLocaleDateString()` on Chromes console is returning 
"2017-6-27". My browser language and PC settings are for UK.

On Firefox it returns 27/06/2017. How can I achieve the same in Chrome or is this a bug?

I know of ways to format a date myself, but is there a way for the browser to consistently pick up the locale and format
itself?

Comment: It seems as there are indeed differences. On my system, Firefox and IE seem to use the date format settings (set to my own language's), while Chrome is apparently using the System locale (set to US). It's not even consistent between IE and Firefox, IE shows `27.06.2017` while Firefox shows `27.6.2017` The simplest option seems to be `toLocaleDateString("uk")`

Comment: how did you check systems locale? Mine seems to be set to English UK

Comment: On Win 7, go to Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Administrative tab

Comment: toLocaleDateString("uk") will work, but i was looking for a locale independent solution, incase people in USA / korea use the web page they would like the date in there format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [toLocaleDateString() is not returning dd/mm/yyyy format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719346/tolocaledatestring-is-not-returning-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

Answer (score 1):

As this question hasn't had a reply yet, and I found it because of this problem still existing in Chrome 97, here is a potential solution:

Open Chrome Settings, then Advanced > Languages.
Drop down the language section. You may now see a few entries for English, eg "English (United Kingdom)", "English" and "English (United States)".
Select the 3 dots next to the specific version of English you want, and ensure the "Display Google Chrome in this language" tickbox is selected.
Restart Chrome when prompted if you change the setting.

For me the "English" option was pre-selected, and this was causing Javascript dates to appear in an American format. The fact that the "UK" option was first in the list didn't make any difference.

Answer (score -3):

A string representing the date portion of the given Date instance according to language-specific conventions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

To be sure of return values, you can overlay this method:

```
Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString = function () {
    return this.getDate() + "/" + (this.getMonth() + 1) + "/" this.getFullYear()
};
```

Comment: I know of ways to format a date, but is there a way for the browser to consistently pick up the locale and format itself?