# Javascript comparison does not work in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I created a calendar only with JavaScript; I need to compare dates of events stored in `<<Element.dataset.date>>` with dates retrieved from database, it works very well with Chrome and Firefox, but not with Edge.

```js
var td = document.querySelector('td');
var date = new Date('2017-06-22');
td.dataset.date = date.toLocaleDateString();
console.log(td.dataset.date === '22/06/2017');

// Output true with Firefox and Chrome but false with Edge
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: `toLocaleDateString` is notoriously unreliable, and even [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) just have questionmarks for Edge support, so you should probably stop using it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I try something else and I keep you informed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22719421/3407923

Comment: Thanks a thousand times, I tried with getFullYear (), getMonth (), and getDate () it works,
Good night and thank you again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.toLocaleDateString() Not Working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002237/tolocaledatestring-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: ^ Despite it saying Not working in Firefox - the answer myfunkyside posted that OP said was helpful simply links to that target above.